# Как реализовать что бы telebot "Python" отправлял рандомную строчку с txt файла

Tags: python, файлы, telegram-bot, telegram

Допустим есть бот и есть список паролей с 8-ми символов каждый пароль начинается с новой строчки, по типу записи \n. Как мне сделать что бы TeleBot на Python отправлял в сообщении рандомную строчку пароля?. Буду благодарен вашей помощи/идеям.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
import random
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("ТОКЕН")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['password'])
def start(message):
    password = random.choice(list(open('passwords.txt')))    
    bot.reply_to(message, f"Пароль - {password}")

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Вместо "ТОКЕН" вставьте свой токен бота от BotFather, а вместо password.txt - путь к файлу с паролями.

Или же так:

```
import random
import telebot
    
bot = telebot.TeleBot("ТОКЕН")
passwords = ["ABCDEFGH", "12345678", "qwertyui"]
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=['password'])
def start(message):
    password = random.choice(passwords)    
    bot.reply_to(message, f"Пароль - {password}")
    
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Разница в том, где хранятся ваши пароли. Почитайте [это](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-random-python/)

Comment: Спасибо большое<3

Comment: отметьте ответ как подходящий пожалуйста)))